# Как осуществить зеркальное отражение фигуры относительно заданной горизонтальной оси?

Tags: графика, геометрия, 2d, масштабирование

Фигура задана в локальных координатах, в глобальные выносится посредством матричного умножения на матрицы масштабирования, поворота, сдвига (в такой же последовательности). Я могу отзеркалить фигуру относительно заданной горизонтальной оси, НО если повернуть фигуру, то отражение уже будет не горизонтальным, знаю что можно умножить матрицу отражения на матрицу поворота -a, потом на a, но не знаю как совместить это с умножениями на матрицы сдвига для отражения относительно заданной горизонтальной оси. Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: scale(1,1,-1) домножить.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков вопрос о том, как корректно масштабировать относительно горизонтальной прямой, если фигура повернута относительно своей оси